# Python Multi-threaded App does not terminate

Tags: python, multithreading

This my code which basically just takes a list of 94,000+ URLs, and collects the http_status codes for them:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
    import threading
    from queue import Queue
    import urllib.request
    import urllib.parse
    from http.client import HTTPConnection
    import socket
    import http.client
    #import httplib

    url_input = open("urls_prod_sort.txt", "r").read()
    urls = url_input[:url_input.rfind('\n')].split('\n')

    #urls = urls[:100]
    url_502 = []
    url_logs = []

    url_502_lock = threading.Lock()
    print_lock = threading.Lock()



    def sendRequest(url_u, http_method = 'GET', data = None):


                    use_proxy = "http://xxxxxxxx:8080"
                    proxies = {"http": use_proxy}
                    proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies)
                    handler = urllib.request.HTTPHandler()
                    url = "http://" + url_u
                    with print_lock:
                                    print(url)
                    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy,handler)
                    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
                    request = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
                    request.add_header("User-agent","| MSIE |")
                    request.get_method = lambda: http_method

                    try:
                                    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
                                    response_code = response.code

                    except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
                                    response_code = error.code

                    except urllib.error.URLError as e2:
                                    response_code = 701

                    except socket.timeout as e3:
                                    response_code = 702

                    except socket.error as e4:
                                    response_code = 703

                    except http.client.IncompleteRead as e:
                                    response_code = 700


                    if response_code == 502:
                                    with url_502_lock:
                                                    #url_502.append(url)
                                                    url_502_file = open("url_502_file.txt", "a")
                                                    url_502_file.write(url + "\n")                                     
                                                    url_502_file.close()

                    with print_lock:
                                    #url_logs.append(url + "," + str(response_code))
                                    url_all_logs_file = open("url_all_logs.csv", "a")
                                    url_all_logs_file.write(url + "," + str(response_code) + '\n')
                                    url_all_logs_file.close()

                                    #print (url + "," + str(response_code))  
                                    #print (response_code)

                    return response_code


    def worker():
                    while True:
                            url = q.get()
                            if url == ":::::"
                                    break
                            else:
                                    sendRequest(url)
                                    q.task_done()


    #======================================


    q = Queue()

    for threads in range(1000):
                    t = threading.Thread(target = worker)
                    t.daemon = True
                    t.start()


    for url in urls:
                    q.put(url)
    q.put(":::::") 
    q.join()
```

However, the program never seems to terminate (even tho the URLs have all been iteratred through) which forces me to ctrl-c the program - and then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./url_sc_checker.py", line 120, in <module>
q.join()
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/queue.py", line 82, in join
self.all_tasks_done.wait()
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/threading.py", line 235, in wait
waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Don't you think that querying 94k links is just a way too long operation?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli according to the question it finished all URLs, but doesn't finish the program. BTW, I'm no expert but does the code spawn 1000 threads?

Comment: I need to query all the URLs I am given, 94k, 94M, however much.

Comment: Yes the above spawns a 1000 threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your program doesn't terminate is simple, your worker creates an infinite loop:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        ...
```

You need to either throw an exception, break, or have a terminating condition in your while statement. Otherwise your program would remain trying to get the next job from the queue, without knowing that there will never be the next job.

A common way to do this is to put a sentinel value in your queue, when checking out a job from the queue, the worker checks if it is the sentinel value and breaks out the loop.

Another way is to have a global condition variable that you check in the while condition. When the job producer have pushed all items to the queue, the job producer joins the queue, and when all jobs are done, the job producer unblocks and terminates the threads our processes.

Another possible reason why your process doesn't terminate is if your sendRequest produces an unexpected exception, then the thread terminates and you'll be left with some jobs that are never marked as done.

Comment: His code is a direct copy of the example here https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#queue-objects